# ASP custom calendar control disappears on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have created a custom calendar control which is working perfect for the most part. My problem is that whenever it posts, the control disappears, even when the user is still hovering. I want them to be able to change months, dates, whatever, without the `divCalendarDropDown` disappearing. Any suggestions?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DateTimePickerObject.ascx.cs" Inherits="DateTimePicker.DateTimePickerObject" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var canHover = true;

    var calendarControl = $(".calendarControl"), flip = $(".divCalendarDropDown"),
    state = $.cookie("ToggleStatus");

    function setCalendarVisibility(className) {
        if (canHover) {
            var dropDown = document.getElementById("divCalendarDropDown");
            dropDown.className = className;
        }
    };
    function OnClick_Calendar() {
        var dropDown = document.getElementById("divCalendarDropDown");
        if (dropDown.style.height >= 1) {
            canHover = true;
            dropDown.className = 'divHidden';
        }
        else {
            canHover = false;
            dropDown.className = 'divNormal';
        };
    };
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .textboxCalendar {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 215px;
    }
    .imgCalendar {
        position: absolute;
        left: 225px;
        top: 0px;
        margin: 0px 5px 0px 4px;
        height: 20px;
        width: auto;
    }
    .imgCalendar:hover {
        margin: 0px 7px 0px 4px;
        height: 21px;
    }
    div {
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        top: 0px;
        margin-top: -2px;
        -webkit-transition:all ease-in-out 1s;
        -moz-transition:all ease-in-out 1s;
        -ms-transition:all ease-in-out 1s;
        -o-transition:all ease-in-out 1s;
        transition:all ease-in-out 1s;
        border-collapse: separate;
    }
        div:hover {
        }
    .divNormal {
        height: 0px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .divHidden {
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .calendar {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma;
        opacity: 1;
    }
        .calendar a {
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
    .calendar th {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #2C5A96;
    }
    .nextPrevStyle {
    }
    .dayHeaderStyle {
    }
    .dayStyle {
        background-color: #E3ECF7;
    }
    .otherMonthDayStyle {
        background-color:  #fbfbfb;
    }
    .selectedDayStyle {
    }
    .titleStyle {
        background-color: #E3ECF7;
    }
    .todayDayStyle {
        background-color: #fbdf93;
    }
    .weekendDayStyle {
        background-color:  #c5d6f1;
    }
    .calendarControl {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        height: auto;
        width: 252px;
    }
</style>
<div class="calendarControl">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textboxCalendar" onMouseOver="setCalendarVisibility('divNormal');" onMouseOut="setCalendarVisibility('divHidden');" onBlur="textboxCalendar_OnBlur()" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="textboxCalendar"></asp:TextBox>
    <span id="spanCalendar" class="spanCalendar"><img id="imgCalendar" src="calendar.png" alt="Calendar" class="imgCalendar" onclick="OnClick_Calendar();"/></span>
    <div id="divCalendarDropDown" onMouseOver="setCalendarVisibility('divNormal');" onMouseOut="setCalendarVisibility('divHidden');">
        <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="calendarMain" OnSelectionChanged="calendarMain_SelectionChanged" CssClass="calendar" NextPrevFormat="CustomText" NextMonthText=">>" PrevMonthText="<<" SelectionMode="Day" >
            <NextPrevStyle CssClass="nextPrevStyle" />
            <DayHeaderStyle CssClass="dayHeaderStyle" />
            <DayStyle CssClass="dayStyle" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle CssClass="otherMonthDayStyle" />
            <SelectedDayStyle CssClass="selectedDayStyle" />
            <TitleStyle CssClass="titleStyle" />
            <TodayDayStyle CssClass="todayDayStyle" />
            <WeekendDayStyle CssClass="weekendDayStyle" />
        </asp:Calendar>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can't avoid postbacks, then you could add an `<asp:HiddenField>` and write some JavaScript which sets its value each time the visibility of the calendar changes. Then when the page loads, read the value of the hidden field with JavaScript and set the initial calendar visibility based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put this in a comment, but I can't yet ; )

I don't think that you can disable the postback to the server with the asp:Calendar control, so try adding a default class to your DIV "divCalendarDropDown" - e.g.

```
<div id="divCalendarDropDown" class="divNormal" onMouseOver="setCalendarVisibility('divNormal');" onMouseOut="setCalendarVisibility('divHidden');">
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try adding another action to that DIV like onblur on onload - e.g.

```
<div id="divCalendarDropDown" onload="setCalendarVisibility('divNormal');" onMouseOver="setCalendarVisibility('divNormal');" onMouseOut="setCalendarVisibility('divHidden');">
```

Hope this helps!  JM